# 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' With Blazor WebAssembly in .NET 8 (with no server-side ASP.NET Core APIs)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor projects.

1. I created a project with Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App template in VS 2022 (Version 17.8.0) with .NET 8 on my Windows machine
2. I am not using server-side code at all (i.e. no ASP.NET Core APIs etc.), other than to download this webassembly app. Therefore there is no server side setup for ASP.NET Core (even if I want to setup CORS policy), at least with currently generated code from the VS template
3. It has the local address at localhost:7113 and I am using Edge browser for testing
4. Updated the code to invoke a remote API endpoint that returns following json:

   ```
   {
       "status": "UP"
   }
   ```
5. It does not require any authentication to invoke it
6. I can hit this endpoint with postman and it returns the above response without any issue
7. However when I use my Blazor code (written in the standalone webassembly project) it throws the following exception:

   > System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
   > TypeError: Failed to fetch
   > --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   > at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.d__13`1[[System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()      at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.CallFetch(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nullable`1 allowAutoRedirect)
   > at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.g__Impl|53_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Nullable`1 allowAutoRedirect)
   > at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   > at BlazorAppStandalone.Services.BlahService.GetPingStatus() in C:\TempCode\BlazorAppStandalone\BlazorAppStandalone\Services\BlahService.cs:line 42
   > at BlazorAppStandalone.Pages.Blah.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\TempCode\BlazorAppStandalone\BlazorAppStandalone\Pages\Blah.razor:line 28
8. The error does not show any information as to what is wrong
9. Thinking that my code may be wrong, I pointed my code to a public API say "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity" and it works flawlessly and get expected response back
10. Thinking that may be my json type is invalid, I used the following code without any custom type (my fetch code as simple as it can get):

    public class GenericService
    {
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    ```
       public GenericService(HttpClient httpClient)
       {
           _httpClient = httpClient;
       }

       public async Task<string> GetStuff()
       {
           //Note: <host.foo.com> is not the actual host
           var response = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://<host.foo.com>/app/ping");

           if (response == null)
           {
               response = "(This response was null after invoking the API";
           }

           return response;
       }
    ```

    }
11. The code causes the above exception up on right on the line with await keyword. So the issue is not my custom type.
12. When I look at the network tab in dev tools in Edge browser, it gives me following info:

```
    General:
    Request URL:https://<host.foo.com>/app/ping   //Note: <host.foo.com> is not the actual host
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 OK
    Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin

    Response Headers:
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:15
    Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date:Sun, 19 Nov 2023 00:19:16 GMT
    Request-Context:appId=cid-v1:a51e1a3d-bc20-47a0-9804-05c5e2952ea8
    Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains

    Request Headers:
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:<host.foo.com>  //Note: <host.foo.com> is not the actual host
    Origin:https://localhost:7113
    Referer:https://localhost:7113/
    Sec-Ch-Ua:"Microsoft Edge";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"
    Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:?0
    Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:"Windows"
    Sec-Fetch-Dest:empty
    Sec-Fetch-Mode:cors
    Sec-Fetch-Site:cross-site
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.60
```

13. There is no response shown in the dev tools in Edge for this endpoint. It shows

> Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier

*I am totally at a loss. No idea what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.*

Additional Details:

1. When I created a Aspnet Web API in a separate project and try to invoke it from the web assembly project, got the exact error. I also tried adding the CORS policy in the API project to allow the origin of the web assembly project. It still failed with same error.
2. I enabled MS code source debugging using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2022. The exception is coming from deep inside the WASM assembly.

```
  Message=
  Source=
  StackTrace:
  at Object.S [as fetch_like] (https://localhost:7113/_framework/dotnet.js:3:4466)
    at https://localhost:7113/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.0.14kkjimq5k.js:3:49419
    at Gr (https://localhost:7113/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.0.14kkjimq5k.js:3:39215)
    at Object.$o [as http_wasm_fetch] (https://localhost:7113/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.0.14kkjimq5k.js:3:49389)
    at https://localhost:7113/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.0.14kkjimq5k.js:3:177853
    at Ul (https://localhost:7113/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.0.14kkjimq5k.js:3:178687)
    at wasm://wasm/00b1e8b6:wasm-function[350]:0x1faee
    at wasm://wasm/00b1e8b6:wasm-function[246]:0x1bf8b
    at wasm://wasm/00b1e8b6:wasm-function[239]:0xf172
    at wasm://wasm/00b1e8b6:wasm-function[273]:0x1d1b0



>   reject [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/loader/promise-controller.ts] Line 30 TypeScript
    <anonymous> [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/cancelable-promise.ts] Line 21   TypeScript
    Promise.catch   
    Gr [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/cancelable-promise.ts] Line 21    TypeScript
    $o [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/http.ts] Line 69  TypeScript
    <anonymous> [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/invoke-js.ts] Line 233   TypeScript
    Ul [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/invoke-js.ts] Line 276    TypeScript
    $func350 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func246 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func239 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func273 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func3184 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2505 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2504 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func1874 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func350 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func246 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func239 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func273 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func3184 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2505 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2511 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2535 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $mono_wasm_invoke_method_bound [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1   JavaScript
    Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method_bound [localhost꞉7113/_framework/dotnet.native.8.0.0.cx60pm2snx.js] Line 8  JavaScript
    kr [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/invoke-cs.ts] Line 273    TypeScript
    <anonymous> [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/invoke-cs.ts] Line 247   TypeScript
    beginInvokeDotNetFromJS [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    invokeDotNetMethodAsync [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    invokeDotNetStaticMethodAsync [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1  JavaScript
    <anonymous> [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    <anonymous> [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    He [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1 JavaScript
    xe [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1 JavaScript
    <anonymous> [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    <anonymous> [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    <anonymous> [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1    JavaScript
    onGlobalEvent [localhost꞉7113/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js] Line 1  JavaScript
==========
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw [c:\Users\rrudra\AppData\Local\SourceServer\bfb16485feaae7af459b6b467db61d095d871d945aa1fa581adaa16efebb78f7\src\libraries\System.Private.CoreLib\src\System\Runtime\ExceptionServices\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs] Line 53   JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs] Line 154 JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs] Line 118    JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs] Line 86 JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>.GetResult [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/TaskAwaiter.cs] Line 515    JavaScript
    System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.CancelationHelper<JSObject> [System.Net.Http.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpInterop.cs] Line 120 JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.<CancelationHelper>d__13<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>>.ExecutionContextCallback [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs] Line 288  JavaScript
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ExecutionContext.cs] Line 179    JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.<CancelationHelper>d__13<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>>.MoveNext [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs] Line 368  JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.<CancelationHelper>d__13<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>>.MoveNext [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs] Line 346  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs] Line 795   JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 3456  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 3432   JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 2137  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 2107    JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 1999    JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 1988    JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 3371   JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>.TrySetException [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource_T.cs] Line 131  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>.SetException [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource_T.cs] Line 88  JavaScript
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSMarshalerArgument.<>c__DisplayClass76_0<JSObject> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/JavaScript/Marshaling/JSMarshalerArgument.Task.cs] Line 108  JavaScript
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JavaScriptExports.CompleteTask [System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/JavaScript/Interop/JavaScriptExports.cs] Line 220 JavaScript
    $func1361 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func1469 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func1510 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func3352 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func346 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func241 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func239 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func273 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func3184 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2505 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2511 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2535 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $mono_wasm_invoke_method_bound [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1   JavaScript
    Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method_bound [localhost꞉7113/_framework/dotnet.native.8.0.0.cx60pm2snx.js] Line 8  JavaScript
    kr [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/invoke-cs.ts] Line 273    TypeScript
    l.javaScriptExports.complete_task [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/managed-exports.ts] Line 142   TypeScript
    <anonymous> [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/marshal-to-cs.ts] Line 347   TypeScript
====

  Message=
  Source=
  StackTrace:





>   System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.CancelationHelper<JSObject> [System.Net.Http.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/BrowserHttpHandler/BrowserHttpInterop.cs] Line 137 JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.<CancelationHelper>d__13<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>>.ExecutionContextCallback [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs] Line 288  JavaScript
    System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ExecutionContext.cs] Line 179    JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.<CancelationHelper>d__13<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>>.MoveNext [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs] Line 368  JavaScript
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject, System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpInterop.<CancelationHelper>d__13<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>>.MoveNext [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncTaskMethodBuilderT.cs] Line 346  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs] Line 795   JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 3456  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 3432   JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 2137  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 2107    JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 1999    JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 1988    JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs] Line 3371   JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>.TrySetException [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource_T.cs] Line 131  JavaScript
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSObject>.SetException [System.Private.CoreLib.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskCompletionSource_T.cs] Line 88  JavaScript
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSMarshalerArgument.<>c__DisplayClass76_0<JSObject> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/JavaScript/Marshaling/JSMarshalerArgument.Task.cs] Line 108  JavaScript
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JavaScriptExports.CompleteTask [System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll//_/src/libraries/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/JavaScript/Interop/JavaScriptExports.cs] Line 220 JavaScript
    $func1361 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func1469 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func1510 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func3352 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func346 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func241 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func239 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func273 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1 JavaScript
    $func3184 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2505 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2511 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $func2535 [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1    JavaScript
    $mono_wasm_invoke_method_bound [wasm/00b1e8b6] Line 1   JavaScript
    Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method_bound [localhost꞉7113/_framework/dotnet.native.8.0.0.cx60pm2snx.js] Line 8  JavaScript
    kr [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/invoke-cs.ts] Line 273    TypeScript
    l.javaScriptExports.complete_task [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/managed-exports.ts] Line 142   TypeScript
    <anonymous> [_framework/https:/raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/5535e31a712343a63f5d7d796cd874e563e5ac14/src/mono/wasm/runtime/marshal-to-cs.ts] Line 347   TypeScript
```

Comment: When I created additional ASPNET Web API project and added CORS policy, I found an issue. Once I corrected it, my web assembly project successfully could invoke this ASPNET Web API. This leads me to believe that the remote API (that is not my ASPNET web API) that I was trying to invoke, probably did not set the CORS policy that allows my calls through web assembly project? Could it be as simple as that?

Comment: That's great! CORS policy is required when you request another domain or remote API because of web security

Comment: Glad to know thta you were able to resolve your issue accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be at the heart of CORS (see relevant standard at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) as the user agent (i.e. browser in this case) enforces the CORS policy after performing the OPTIONS (typically called prefetch) API call to the remote server.

Unless the remote server responds with relevant origin value (which in this case should be https://localhost:7113 OR simply * for any origin) for Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header and relevant verb value (which in this case is **GET** in the list) for Access-Control-Allow-Methods in browser's OPTIONS http verb call to this remote API, the browser will not attempt to make the GET call to the remote server.

The error in this post does not appear to be Blazor fault at all. The dev tools in the browser surface the CORS errors not in network tab but elsewhere, which I missed seeing before.

The tools like postman or curl do not enforce the CORS policy and hence those tools happily invoke the relevant APIs. So does any custom written tools. Because CORS policies appear to be implemented by browser user agents only.

Here is an example of curl command for OPTIONS API call (mimicking how the browser would do it) to a remote server that is configured with appropriate CORS and the response (Note: The remote server in this example is *https://localhost:7217* and origin is *https://localhost:7113*) (Note the success responsecode: 204)

```
curl -H "Origin: https://localhost:7113" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -X OPTIONS --verbose https://localhost:7217/WeatherForecast/Ping
*   Trying [::1]:7217...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 7217
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> OPTIONS /WeatherForecast/Ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7217
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: https://localhost:7113
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Date: Tue, 21 Nov 2023 18:40:59 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:7113
< Vary: Origin
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Here is an example of curl command to a remote server that is NOT configured with appropriate CORS and the response (Note the non-success response status code: 405):

```
curl -H "Origin: https://localhost:7113" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -X OPTIONS --verbose https://localhost:7217/WeatherForecast/Ping
*   Trying [::1]:7217...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 7217
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* using HTTP/1.1
> OPTIONS /WeatherForecast/Ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:7217
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: https://localhost:7113
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 21 Nov 2023 18:39:06 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Allow: GET
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```